# some url does not redirect from http to https

Tags: redirect, htaccess, https

I am trying to solve my https redirection from all away.I follow the all solutions form stackexchange. But still in problem so I am writing here.
Problem is that https redirection is working but some url not redirect.
For example .
http://example.com/contact not redirect on http://example.com/contact.
This is my code .

```
define( 'WP_CACHE', false );

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('WP_HOME','https://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.example.com');
```

Thanks for support .

Answer (score 2):

Your code redirects the WordPress admin pages to use https (which will work fine), and then sets the site and WordPress addresses (which may auto redirect some pages). Note that FORCE_SSL_LOGIN was deprecated in WordPress version 4.0 (https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Over_SSL)

You can force the whole site to use SSL using .htaccess (note to cover WordPress installs to their own directory, it should be the .htaccess in the same server directory that the Site home would use).

Usually that would be:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

but some hosts require an environment variable:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

If you're using Windows hosting .htaccess won't work, you'll need to use web.config

```
<rule name="HTTPS" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

### Related Considerations

I'd recommend you change all links under your control to use https. Within WordPress the https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ is very handy for this.

You should consider changing the WordPress URL and the Site URL in the admin instead, and take a look at this good overall guide to migrating WordPress to use https https://reviewofweb.com/how-to/migrate-wordpress-from-http-to-https/

Comment: Good answer.  Another option for a global search and replace is WP CLI.

Comment: @query-builder I think you were trying to talk to me but posted under the other answer. Your htaccess below just needs to have https:// in front of your domain to get rid of your endless redirect problem. The site you mentioned loads the http contact page with one 301 redirect to https so you've probably already done that. If my answer helped, please accept it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use [Really simple SSL plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/). Or Htaccess code can fix this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: I just included htacess code

Comment: intinerant@ here is my .htaccess  ..........# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.origin.com.sg/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: intinerant@After this getting to many redirection. I have changed site url and home url from admin. http to https

Comment: Please don't recommend plugins in/as an answer. Because the possibility is always around that the plugin is/will be deleted for whatever reason and in such case would your answer be useless.